# Angular - Multiple ng-templates grouping, and show hide those on condition

Tags: angular, angular-template

So I have this structure on a view like this

```
<ng-template '#body'>
<div *ngif="isAnswerA; else answerB">
<section>... </section>
</div>

<ng-template '#answerB'>
<section>... </section>
</ng-template>

<ng-template '#footer'>
<section>... </section>
</ng-template>
```

Now, I have to introduce an alternative body, and for that initial header and footer needs to be hidden and the new alternative body needs to be shown on a condition

Something similar to this

```
    If <some_god_knows_condition == true> {
show => template Header(ng-template) + Footer(ng-template) 
}
    else { show = > Alternative_Template_No_Header_NoFooter }
```

My question is there a way to group header and footer template so that I can toggle them together and use my third ng-template on a given condition.

Comment: Can't you just use  `*ngIf="condition"` and  `*ngIf="!condition"` So `<ng-template *ngIf="condition" #header ></ng-template>  <ng-template *ngIf="condition" #footer ></ng-template> <ng-template *ngIf="!condition" #alternative ></ng-template>`

Comment: @DevEng : That's what I want to avoid. I am wondering how can I just group two ng-templates in 1, and toggle them with 1 check instead of multiple

Answer (score 0):

> *ngIf may not work correctly because angular converts *ngIf  to ng-template

```js
isSome_god_knows_condition = true;

<ng-template [ngIf]="isSome_god_knows_condition" #Header ></ng-template>
<ng-template [ngIf]="isSome_god_knows_condition" #Footer ></ng-template>
<ng-template [ngIf]="!isSome_god_knows_condition" #Alternative_Template ></ng-template>
```